# Google Drive API : 401 Unauthorized

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to integrate Google Drive API and am getting error in all projects but the same code its working in my one of the project. can any one help to solve this issue.

this is my code to upload pdf file:

```
private void googleDrive(String file1, final String fileName) {
    if (mDriveServiceHelper == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.show();}
    mDriveServiceHelper.uploadFile(new File(file1), "application/pdf", null)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleDriveFileHolder>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(GoogleDriveFileHolder googleDriveFileHolder) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Log.d("drive", "onSuccess: " + gson.toJson(googleDriveFileHolder));
                    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fileName + " is uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fileName + " is failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

---

And am getting error like this:

```
D/MainActivity: onFailure: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "required",
      "message": "Login Required",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization"
    }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
}
```

Comment: How are you authenticating and authorizing the code?

Comment: `GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
 mGoogleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
 startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);`